# Sequelize : Using 'where' in 'include' in findByPk

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

In Sequelize I´m using findByPk but I also need to pass another condition

```
return dependencies.db.models.user.findByPk(userId, {
        include: [
            {
                model: dependencies.db.models.userGroup,
                required: false,
                where: {
                    Time: null,
                },
```

I know that 'options.where' is not supported for findByPk , however it is being used inside of a include.
I couldn't find verification in the sequelize documentation that what I am doing is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return dependencies.db.models.user.findByPk(userId, {
        include: [
            {
                model: dependencies.db.models.userGroup,
                required: false,
                where: {
                    Time: { [op.eq]:null }
                },
```